# Test if string begins with a string?

Tags: vba

In VBA, what's the most straight forward way to test if a string begins with a substring?  Java has `startsWith`.  Is there a VBA equivalent?

Comment: Do you know the length of the substring you want to find?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

### InStr

You can use the `InStr` build-in function to test if a String contains a substring.  `InStr` will either return the index of the first match, or 0.  So you can test if a String begins with a substring by doing the following:

```
If InStr(1, "Hello World", "Hello W") = 1 Then
    MsgBox "Yep, this string begins with Hello W!"
End If
```

If `InStr` returns `1`, then the String ("Hello World"), begins with the substring ("Hello W").

### Like

You can also use the `like` comparison operator along with some basic pattern matching:

```
If "Hello World" Like "Hello W*" Then
    MsgBox "Yep, this string begins with Hello W!"
End If
```

In this, we use an asterisk (*) to test if the String begins with our substring.

Comment: `InStr` does the job, but it doesn't seem to be a `Like` in VBScript (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30301238/61508)

Answer (score 52):

Judging by the [declaration and description of the `startsWith` Java function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_startswith.htm), the "most straight forward way" to implement it in VBA would either be with `Left`:

```
Public Function startsWith(str As String, prefix As String) As Boolean
    startsWith = Left(str, Len(prefix)) = prefix
End Function
```

Or, if you want to have the offset parameter available, with `Mid`:

```
Public Function startsWith(str As String, prefix As String, Optional toffset As Integer = 0) As Boolean
    startsWith = Mid(str, toffset + 1, Len(prefix)) = prefix
End Function
```

Comment: This also has the bonus of being faster to execute than armstrhb's solution (his solution is however easier to read and code).

Comment: ...and to check if it ends with the substring, just use `Right()` instead: `Right(str, Len(prefix)) = prefix` :-)

Comment: You'll also speed it up a teeeeeny bit by using the Mid$(...) function or Left$(...) functions (which allow the string variable to be passed straight in without being wrapped up in a Variant)

Answer (score 3):

The best methods are already given but why not look at a couple of other methods for fun? Warning: these are more expensive methods but do serve in other circumstances.

The expensive regex method and the css attribute selector with starts with ^ operator

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Debug.Print StartWithSubString("ab", "abc,d")

End Sub
```

---

**Regex:**

```
Public Function StartWithSubString(ByVal substring As String, ByVal testString As String) As Boolean
    'required reference Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions
    Dim re As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Set re = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

    re.Pattern = "^" & substring

    StartWithSubString = re.test(testString)

End Function
```

---

**Css attribute selector with starts with operator**

```
Public Function StartWithSubString(ByVal substring As String, ByVal testString As String) As Boolean
    'required reference Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    html.body.innerHTML = "<div test=""" & testString & """></div>"

    StartWithSubString = html.querySelectorAll("[test^=" & substring & "]").Length > 0

End Function
```