# VBS using LIKE to compare strings "Sub or Function not defined"

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to make a script to connect a network printer to a user computer. 
The script uses the computer name who needs the printer as a parameter.

Printers names are similar their printserver name, eg. server_USA has printers like printer_USA01, printer_USA02.

But it's throwing the error "Sub or Function not defined" when arrives at the first like... why ?

```
Set shl = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strName = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)

'input Printer name
strPrinter = InputBox("Please enter share name of printer to install:", _
    "Add network printer")

if strPrinter = "" then
    msgbox "Can't be empty."
    WScript.quit

elseif strPrinter Like "printer_USA*" then
    strServer = server_USA

elseif strPrinter Like "printer_SPAIN*" then
    strServer = server_SPAIN

else
    'Printer name NOT registered, input printserver manually:
    strServer = inputbox("Please enter the name of the printserver","printserver")

    if strServer = "" then
        msgbox "Can't be empty."
        WScript.quit
    End if

End if

'ADD
shl.run "RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /ga /c\\" & strName & " /n\\" & strServer & "\" & strPrinter
```

Comment: To my knowledge the `Like` operator is not supported in VBS. Try it with InStr instead

Answer (score 11, accepted):

there is no Like operator in VBScript. You could use [Instr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c.aspx).

```
if strPrinter = "" then
    msgbox "Can't be empty."
    WScript.quit

elseif Instr( 1, strPrinter, "printer_USA", vbTextCompare ) > 0 then
    strServer = server_USA
```

The vbTextCompare constant ( value=1) is used to *Perform a textual comparison*

Answer (score 0):

you can use **`StrComp`**  to have same result in this way

```
    If StrComp(strPrinter,"printer_USA",vbTextCompare)=0 then  
    strServer = server_USA
    End IF
```

equal **`0`** mean zero different between **`strPrinter`** and **`printer_USA`** with ignore the letter case because we use **`vbTextCompare`** .

You can replace **`vbTextCompare`** with **`1`** and you will have same result.

If letter case is important you can use **`vbBinaryCompare`** or **`0`**.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do that with select case.  This version of instr() is case sensitive, but other versions aren't.  instr() returns the position of the found substring, which here is always one.

```
select case 1
  case instr(strPrinter, "") + 1
    wscript.echo "empty"
  case instr(strPrinter, "printer_USA")
    wscript.echo "server_USA"
  case instr(strPrinter, "printer_SPAIN")
    wscript.echo "server_SPAIN"
  case instr(strPrinter, "printer_ITALY"), instr(strPrinter, "printer_RUSSIA")
    wscript.echo "other known ones"
  case else
    wscript.echo "not registered"
end select
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following alternative (VBScript Regular Expressions)…
Uses slightly different syntax from LIKE but easiest solution to make a match successfully similar to LIKE operator.

```
dim regExp
set regExp=CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
regExp.IgnoreCase = true
regExp.Global = true
regxp.Pattern = ".*Test Pattern.*" ' example only, basic pattern

if regExp.Test(MyString) then
    ' match successful
end if
```