# Read text file and write ONLY lines with certain text

Tags: text, vbscript, scripting

So, I am trying to comb through a large text file for only certain lines that include certain text. Want to write the whole line to a new text file. This is what I came up with, but it completly empties the taget text file and gives me the error "Input past end of file".

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFile = "C:\Users\Choti\Desktop\collect\collect.L"
strTemp = "C:\Users\Choti\Desktop\collect\temp.txt"
Set objFile = objFS.GetFile(strFile)
Set objOutFile = objFS.CreateTextFile(strTemp,True)
Set ts = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(1,-2)
Do Until ts.AtEndOfStream = false
    strLine = ts.ReadLine
    ' do something with strLine
    if strLine like "tagId" Then
    objOutFile.Write(strLine)
    end if 
    ts.AtEndOfStream = false
Loop
objOutFile.Close
ts.Close
objFS.DeleteFile(strFile)
objFS.MoveFile strTemp,strFile
```

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Working Code

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strFile = "C:\Users\Choti\Desktop\collect\collect.L"
strTemp = "C:\Users\Choti\Desktop\collect\temp.txt"

Set objFile = objFS.GetFile(strFile)
Set objOutFile = objFS.CreateTextFile(strTemp,True)
Set ts = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(1,-2)

Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = ts.ReadLine


    if Instr(1, strLine, "tagId") > 0 Then
       objOutFile.WriteLine strLine

    end if


Loop 
objOutFile.Close
ts.Close
```

Comment: You're not checking to see if a line *includes* "tagId", but instead whether the line equals "tagId".  Use `Instr()` or `Like` to check whether a string is included in another string.  And what are you doing with count/counter ?

Comment: I just realised that and updated it, but now im getting Input past end of file. It is also deleting everything from the target text file

Comment: Is this VBA or VBScript? One has a `Like` operator, the other doesn't.

Comment: VBScript, but I switched to using `Instr()` but it is not outputing

Comment: If you're using VBScript, how does the answer you accepted work for you? And if it doesn't, why did you accept it in the first place? If the problem is still unresolved, please update your question with your current non-working code. If you're getting errors, include those as well.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The answer provided clears up the confusion and it was syntax issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strFile = "C:\Users\Choti\Desktop\collect\collect.L"
strTemp = "C:\Users\Choti\Desktop\collect\temp.txt"

Set objFile = objFS.GetFile(strFile)
Set objOutFile = objFS.CreateTextFile(strTemp,True)

Set ts = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(1,-2)

Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream

    strLine = ts.ReadLine
    ' do something with strLine
    'if Instr(1, strLine, "tagId") > 0 'vbscript/VBA
    if strLine Like "*tagId*" Then     'VBA
       objOutFile.WriteLine strLine
    end if 

Loop

objOutFile.Close
ts.Close

objFS.DeleteFile strFile 
objFS.MoveFile strTemp,strFile
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting

Comment: Error: Sub or Function not defined on Line 15 Char 5

Comment: What line is that?  If you click Debug which line is highlighted?

Comment: 'if strLine like "*tagId*" Then'

Comment: You've tagged your question with both VBa and vbscript - which are you actually using?  If vbscript see  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30301118/vbs-using-like-to-compare-strings-sub-or-function-not-defined