# VBscript - multiline IF statement yielding error

Tags: date, if-statement, vbscript

I have a basic script that was working no problem for a year. Recently, I've tried to add an `IF` statement to it, so if the current date is a particular day of the year i.e. January 18, then do not Msgbox. I thought it would be fairly straight forward, but ran into `Sub or Function not defined` on the first line of the IF statement that I cannot seem to resolve on my own:

```
If Not CStr(Date()) Like  "1/18/*" _ 
And Not CStr(Date()) Like "2/15/*" _
And Not CStr(Date()) Like "12/31/*" Then
MsgBox "perform task"
Else
MsgBox "do not perform task"
End If
```

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: This can be answered here: [VBS using LIKE to compare strings “Sub or Function not defined”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30301118/vbs-using-like-to-compare-strings-sub-or-function-not-defined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no **Like** operator in VBScript. One way to achieve what you are trying to do would be:

```
MonthAndDay = Month(Date) & "/" & Day(Date)

If MonthAndDay <> "1/18" _
   and MonthAndDay <> "2/15" _
   and MonthAndDay <> "12/31" Then
   MsgBox "perform task"
Else
   MsgBox "do not perform task"
End If
```