# Replacing long string values

Tags: excel, vba, string, replace

I have many rows with the first cell (column A) with a long string value (around 100 characters)

I am trying to replace these long string values with shorter ones:

```
Sub text_replacement()

Dim row As Range
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveSheet

For i = 1 To sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Set row = sheet.Rows(i)
    If Cells(i, 1) = "This is a long string value*" Then
        Cells(i, 1).Value = "Short and standard value"
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

I am using the "*" because all these long string values always starts the same. I don't know what is not working, but the below code does not have any effect on the values (and it does not give me any error either)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wildcards don't work with `=`. However, much more efficient to use [`Range.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace), which does support wildcards, and no loop.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Replace _
   What:="This is a long string value*", _
   Replacement:="Short and standard value", _
   LookAt:=xlWhole
```

Answer (score 2):

You're expecting the `*` at the end of the string to match any value after that string. This is not how the `=` comparator works. `=` requires that the values be exactly the same.

You want to check if the string starts with the key value.  In VBA, this can be done a few ways - check the answers to this question:

[Test if string begins with a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802870/test-if-string-begins-with-a-string)